# Replace css background url

Tags: javascript, regex

i would like to replace the css background urls like these:

```
body {
  background: url("../common/images/nyau.jpg") center center;
}
.alma { 
  background: url("./vau/vau.jpg"); 
}
.ata { 
  background: url("./mak.jpg"); 
}
```

to these:

```
body {
  background: url("./images/nyau.jpg") center center;
}
.alma { 
  background: url("./images/vau.jpg"); 
}
.ata { 
  background: url("./images/mak.jpg"); 
}
```

Unfortunately i am not familiar with regex at all.

I know i can select `("../common/images/nyau.jpg")` this part with `/\((.*?)\)/g` but i need to capture the part from the last `/` (nyau.jpg) somehow. So i could do `./images/$1` or something like that.

**EDIT:** in the api of `gulp-replace` i am only allowed to use regular expressions without any javascript function.

Comment: What is purpose of separate lines for each `background` property ? Last `background` set would overwrite previous two

Comment: `bg = './images/' + bg.split('/').pop()`

Comment: @adeneo we both had the same idea

Comment: You are right, maybe i shouldn't have come up with such a silly example. But in this case it is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function `fixPath(path)` will return you the path as you want it to have, you can then apply it whereever you need to fix you backgrounds.

```js
function fixPath(path) {
  return path.replace(/(.*\/)(.*)$/, "./images/$2")
  //  return "./images/" + path.split("/").pop()
}

// Demo Paths
var paths = ["../common/images/nyau.jpg", "./vau/vau.jpg", "./mak.jpg"]

// Do it for all paths
paths = paths.map(fixPath)

// Demo Output
document.write(JSON.stringify(paths))
```

Comment: unfortunately i can only use regex and no javascript functions

Comment: @AttilaEgyed whs is that? But OK, i'll find the regex

Comment: @CodeSir check regexr.com, i use `gulp-replace` and in that api i am only allowed to use regular expressions without any javascript function

Comment: @AttilaEgyed I added the RegEx

Comment: @CodeSir nice! But this will also replace all regular urls like this `http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar` for example. The best would be to make some constraint to only look for the contents between `url(...)`

Comment: I just had to slightly modify your solution and now works perfectly `/\((.*\/)(.*?)\)/g, '("../images/$2)'`. Thanks a lot!